# Read raw C string to Rust... what's the right way to convert signed to unsigned in this context?

Tags: c, string, vector, utf-8, rust

I'm binding some C functions to rust. I'm facing a little problem and I'd like to know the right way to solve it in rust.

Here's the function that I'd like to call from the C API:

```
extern "C" {
    pub fn H5Aread(attr_id: hid_t, type_id: hid_t, buf: *mut c_char) -> herr_t;
}
```

The function reads something from a file, and stores it in `buf`.

So, I created this buffer in a vector:

```
let len: u64 = get_the_length();

let attr_raw_string: Vec<c_char> = Vec::new(); // c_char is equivalent to i8
attr_raw_string.resize(len as usize, 0);
let attr_raw_string_ptr = attr_raw_string.as_mut_ptr();

let read_error = H5Aread(attr_obj, attr_type, attr_raw_string_ptr);
if read_error < 0 {
    panic!("...");
}
let result_str: String = String::from_utf8(attr_raw_string);
```

Now this doesn't compile because `from_utf8` expects a `Vec<u8>`, but `Vec<c_char>` is a `Vec<i8>`.

Is there a way to fix this without having to copy and cast the string every time as a new type `u8`?

Comment: @klutt This is not C++, it's Rust. Ever seen `let` in C++? I tagged it with C because it's about a C API.

Comment: My bad. Sorry. It's just that tagging C instead of C++ that's a very common thing to do.

Comment: Is `buf` a C string? i.e., should it be null terminated? Or is this an unterminated byte buffer that happens to be UTF-8?

Comment: @trentcl It's a C string that's null terminated. I'm not sure the null exists or not, I have to double check, but either way, I have to add the null if necessary.

Comment: You'll want to use `CString` or `Cstr`. I can't write a full answer at the moment, but maybe those search terms will help.

Comment: @trentcl Unfortunately, I don't see a way to allocate a buffer with `CString`, that I write to. It seems `CString` is designed to take a string that will later be used as a pointer, not the other way around (where you create a buffer and fill it from C API with data).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were almost there.

For now, we're going to assume that the C side of your FFI boundary is correct - i.e. it properly generates a null-terminated string.

To efficiently assign and recover this in rust, we're going to use `CStr`. This creates a borrowed type referencing a C string in memory (i.e. a `*const char`). This does not allocate, since it is not an owned type.

We then convert this to a `&str` for the final comparison with what we expected. This is still not an owned type, so all we have created is our `Vec<>` that we effectively used as a buffer.

The full code is available below and on the [**playground**](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=8b02133f9fe62c8b4bac4b7fc00613f4):

```
#[test]
fn test() {
    let len:u64 = 64;
    // Allocate a buffer
    let mut buffer:Vec<c_char> = Vec::with_capacity(len as usize);
    let attr_raw_string_ptr = buffer.as_mut_ptr();

    let read_error = unsafe { H5Aread(attr_raw_string_ptr) };
    if read_error < 0 {
        panic!("...");
    }
    let result = unsafe {
        CStr::from_ptr(attr_raw_string_ptr)
    };
    let result_str = result.to_str().unwrap();
    assert_eq!(result_str, "test");
}
```

Three important gotchas:

1. `CStr::to_str()` can fail (hence why it returns a `Result<&str, _>` when the content of the `CStr` is not valid utf-8. This is because both the rust `String` and `&str` types need to be valid utf-8.
2. Obviously, your input buffer needs to be at least the size of what your C function will throw into it. Refer to the C side to be able to make this guarantee.
3. `CStr::from_ptr` has a [bunch of gotchas](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ffi/struct.CStr.html#method.from_ptr) that you should at least keep in mind when using it

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'll try this solution and tick it after testing it. I'll need some time to come to a result due to other complications.

Comment: @TheQuantumPhysicist Let me know if it worked, and if not, I'll be happy to provide more guidance if I can :-)

Comment: Also, do note that if you know the maximum size of your buffer ahead of time, it will be faster to use an array as a buffer (and sacrifice the extensibility of `Vec`) to store your data. Principle is the same, methods are the same, the only difference is the allocation.

Comment: Today I got a chance to test the solution. It's working, but valgrind is shooting an error at `CStr::from_ptr()`. The error is: `Invalid read of size 1
  in <alloc::string::String as data_handler_server::ReadAttribute>::get_attribute_value`, and a suberror `Address 0x6a8df52 is 0 bytes after a block of size 2 alloc'd`. I'm not sure what to do about this. Can you please test it on your end too?

Comment: Show me what you're testing and I'll happily test on my end. The code I've put on the playground is exactly what I put in, minus `H5Aread`, and it doesn't leak. Put your code somewhere and I'll see if I can find it

Comment: No, forget it. It's my fault. I allocated the wrong length because the lib doesn't count null, so valgrind was complaining about boundaries. Thanks for your help :-)

Comment: Anytime! Glad to have helped :-)